# How not to display the created_by field but auto-populate it with the current user keeping the unique_together rule?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

My model assumes that each User (let's say it's a doctor) can have his own Patients. Hence, the Patient model has a 'created_by' field for the currently logged in User. Each doctor (i.e.User) should only have one Patient with the same first and second name (e.g. John Smith), but a different doctor (i.e. other User) can have again a patient called e.g. John Smith. Hence, I've marked the three fields: first_name, last_name, created_by as unique_together.

```
class Patient(models.Model):
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)

    class Meta:
         unique_together = (("created_by","first_name", "last_name"),)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the 'created_by' field should not appear in the form, but should be auto-populated.Here's the ModelForm:

```
class PatientForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Patient
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self,request):
        obj = super(PatientForm, self).save(commit = False)
        obj.created_by = request.user
        obj.save()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(PatientForm, self).clean()

        first_name = cleaned_data.get('first_name')
        last_name = cleaned_data.get('last_name')
        created_by = cleaned_data.get('created_by')

        if Patient.objects.filter(first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name, created_by = created_by).exists():
            raise ValidationError('This name already exists!')
        else:
            return cleaned_data
```

Here's the problem: As you can see the ModelForm contains the 'created_by' field. If I exclude it using the ModelForm the unique_together validation will not work. If I don't display the 'created_by' field in the template it will fail in the view during the form.is_valid() validation step.

How not to display the created_by field but auto-populate it with the current user keeping the unique_together rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django already [validates the uniqueness](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L435) of your model for you, there's no need to do it yourself. The trick is to make sure the `created_by` field is set before the model is validated, i.e. if you're creating a new patient:

```
p = Patient(created_by=request.user)
form = PatientForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=p)
```

There's no need to add the `created_by` field to the form - unless the current user is just a default value and the doctor can add another doctor's patients to the system. In both cases, Django itself checks that your `Patient` follows the `unique_together` constraints.

Comment: Great - by adding those 2 lines of code and adding null=True to the created_by field in my model it ... worked ! :) Thank you so much !!